# Websocket server won't connect if started via PHP

Tags: networking, users, environment-variables, php, socket

I have a websocket server written in Node. The following instruction, when executed from the command line starts the websocket server successfully:

```
nohup "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/bin/node" "/var/www/bm-server/bm-server" 1337 > "/var/www/bm-server/logs.txt" 2>&1 &
```

I can see that the server is running because `pgrep -x "bm-server"` displayes the PID.

I know the port is open and listening because `# netstat -an | grep ":1337"` produces:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::1337                 :::*                    LISTEN
```

I know the port is accessible because `telnet myhost 1337` successfully connects from another machine.

And my web app can connect to and use the server as expected.

**The problem is** that I want to start the program via PHP:

```
exec('nohup "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.1/bin/node" "/var/www/bm-server/bm-server" 1337 > "/var/www/bm-server/logs.txt" 2>&1 &', $stdout, $exitcode);
```

That command, when run from PHP passes all the same tests as above, except when connecting from the browser. I can connect with telnet just fine, but when I try to connect from the browser I get

```
failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_CLOSED
```

It has to have something to do with the environment in which PHP executes the code. I can't figure out what could possibly be affected by that in the script though.

Here's the [source for the server](https://github.com/Pamblam/browser-mirror/blob/master/bm-server), if it mattters.

What is the problem with the PHP user (www-data) starting the server? BTW I also gave www-data permission to run sudo without a password and tried it with sudo as well, but that didn't make a difference.